# Bringing up to the front a program's secondary window without changing focus from the primary window

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have a main window/form for my program, and a partner-in-crime window/form, shown/hidden on request. I would like both of them to be in the front when the main window is called to the front (e.g by Alt-Tab).

Trying to use the main window's Activated function and using the partner window's `Focused` or `Activate` functions calls focus to the partner window when said partner window is `Visible`, and the problem is that at that point, every time I try to click on the main window (y'know, to use it), I focus on it, meaning that it brings focus to the partner window instead.

How do I bring a partner window up to the front while keeping focus on the main window?

With hope,

radzo73

Comment: When you display your "partner-in-crime" form, pass in the main form as the owner via [Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netcore-3.1).  Now the secondary form should "stick" with the main form...

Answer (score 0):

I have found this first-line solution that works but can certainly be improved or adapted:

```
private Timer ActivatedTimer;
private bool ActivatedMutex;
```

```
public FormTest()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ActivatedTimer = new Timer();
  ActivatedTimer.Interval = 10;
  ActivatedTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
  {
    ActivatedTimer.Stop();
    try
    {
      ActivatedMutex = true;
      BringToFront();
    }
    finally
    {
      ActivatedMutex = false;
    }
  };
}
```

```
private void FormTest_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ( ActivatedMutex ) return;
  try
  {
    ActivatedMutex = true;
    foreach ( Form form in Application.OpenForms )
      if ( form != this && form.Visible )
        form.BringToFront();
    ActivatedTimer.Start();
  }
  finally
  {
    ActivatedMutex = false;
  }
}
```

Perhaps there are some Win32APIs to do that better.